# Struct is fileprivate and cannot be referenced from a default argument value in swift 4.1

Tags: swift, default-value, swift4.1

Im using a struct with default values like this.

```
 fileprivate struct Defaults {

    static var BackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    static var TextColor = UIColor.black
    static var Title = "Default Title"
    static var Message = "Default message!"
    static var AnimationDuration: Double = 0.25
    static var Duration: Double = 2
    static var Height: CGFloat = 90
    static var TitleFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Semibold", size: Defaults.FontSize)!
    static var MessageFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: Defaults.FontSize)!
    static var FontSize: CGFloat = 14 {
        didSet {
            TitleFont = TitleFont.withSize(FontSize)
            MessageFont = MessageFont.withSize(FontSize)
        }
    }
}
```

I have a method in which passing the these struct values as a default arguments. But in swift4 it's not working.

```
 class func showWithAnimation(_ animationType: AnimationType = .basic(timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)),
                             title: String = Defaults.Title,
                             message: String = Defaults.Message,
                             backgroundColor: UIColor = Defaults.BackgroundColor,
                             textColor: UIColor = Defaults.TextColor,
                             duration: Double = Defaults.Duration) {

}
```

Please check the total code [here](https://gist.github.com/perlasivakrishna/b5cd2e2dd095297bf244b15a52dee1db).

What's the work around for this ?

Thankyou...

Comment: What is issue ? what is not working ?

Comment: Why make a struct that holds default values to be used in your app and then restrain it to be fileprivate? It is counterintuitive. Also, why are your properties in Default declared as var, shouldn't default values be constant?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes. I can make them let. The purpose i take them as a struct I just want to seperate from other constants.

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't use a struct, I was questioning why it is declared fileprivate because it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I deleted fileprivate. still im not able to use as arguments

Comment: Please check full code

Comment: @SivakrishnaPerla one solution added on your gist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two fixes as stated below,

**1)** Take `Defaults` `struct` out of `DropdownAlert` and make it `public` even `properties` also as you want to pass them in method signature as below,

```
public struct Defaults {
    public static var BackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    public static var TextColor = UIColor.black
    public static var Title = "Default Title"
}

class func showWithAnimation(_ animationType: AnimationType = .basic(timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)),
                                     title: String = Defaults.Title,
                                     message: String = Defaults.Message) {
    }
```

**2)** Keep `Defaults` inside `DropdownAlert` but make it `public` including `properties` also. And access as below,

```
class func showWithAnimation(_ animationType: AnimationType = .basic(timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)),
                                 title: String = DropdownAlert.Defaults.Title,
                                 message: String = DropdownAlert.Defaults.Message) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karman. May i know Why its not working swift4,  where as its working swift3

Comment: @SivakrishnaPerla can you share the error you are facing in Swift4?

Comment: I mean After changing to public its working in swift4. Before changing It's working in swift3